# Comparing web app performance on multiple deployment environments

Tags: web-applications, development-environment, performance-testing, production-environment

I have attempting to isolate performance differences I am having between my test environment and my QA and Production environments.  I'm having large page load delays on my non-test environments as well as much longer access times for data retrieval.

I have performed some hourly manual testing by monitoring specific calls in the Network tab of the DevTools in chrome and used Kibana to monitor my web server performance.  I believe I have isolated the issue to server calls for page resources (css, js) on page load and data calls for loading summary information.

Any suggestions of tools or techniques I can use to isolate my problems to a specific piece of hardware or process?  Page load and data access are five times (or more) longer on my non-test environments.  If nothing else, I need a way to at least prove the difference is constant and not based on circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

To me the best solution is to use an APM tool: it can show you very quickly where the bottleneck is. For the most common languages/environments they can instrument the code and show you where the problems are.
NewRelic can be free and it's very easy. Try it.
AppDynamics is more powerful and you can register for a trial. Dynatrace is the top for me but is quite difficult to use.

Comment: Thanks, that'll get me started and I'll comment again if I need more information.  Much appreciated.

Comment: These were not what I was looking for.  I was hoping for methods or tools I could use myself without going through a third party for results (not having a third party involved at all, if possible).  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: I don't know what you mean for "third party". New Relic offer is tool only as SaaS but AD and DT offer their tools both on premise or SaaS. You could buy a license, install on your servers and do all your analysis. They both offer free trial licenses.
After you learn how to use them you won't find any quicker solution to diagnose a performance issue.

Comment: Understood, I started with the New Relic and assumed they were all SaaS after that.  Thanks again cristian